Selenium-Jupiter - Using only local Browsers/Drivers
I'd like to use the selenium-jupiter JUnit5 extension for CI/CD runs:
selenium-jupiter
Unfortunately the used WebDriverManager is dynamically fetching browsers/drivers from the internet.
To allow for a controlled execution I'd like to force it to only use executables that are provided via the SCM and to always use a dedicated version of the selected browser executable.
Not the one installed in the system.
Is there a way to configure the selenium-jupiter extension and the WebDriverManager to not reach out to the internet and to use a predefined browser executable?
Even when setting cachePath(String) and resolutionCachePath(String) there are still some heuristics running in the background.

Selenium-Jupiter uses WebDriverManager internally for diver management, and I am afraid it cannot be skipped.
On the other hand, Selenium is going to use Selenium Manager for driver management.
So, if you have your custom browser and driver, my recommendation is to stop using Selenium-Jupiter and instantiate your ChromeDriver (supposing you are using Chrome) as follows:
File myDriver = new File("/path/to/chromedriver");
ChromeDriverService driverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
        .usingDriverExecutable(myDriver).build();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
File myBrowser = new File("/path/to/chrome");
options.setBinary(myBrowser);
    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);


Thanks for the information. I did find a way using the getConfig().setManager() function and providing an initialized WDM where the browserBinary in the capabilities is pointing to a local browser version. Not the most elegant approach, but it works ;-)
I'd like to take full advantage of the convenience of the extension, esp. also he docker suport.

@JensStockhausen - can you please provide your implementation as an answer. I'd like to pretty much get a similar setup done as well. Thanks

@Boni Garcia - I am using the latest 5.1.1 and I get  an error
[main] INFO org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec - Recoverable I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://googlechromelabs.github.io:443
However from the browser I see that URL is throwing a 404.

@user1126946: An abreviated walkthrough:
Extend the SeleniumJupiter extension
public class SeleniumExtension extends SeleniumJupiter
overwrite resolveParameter and before you call delegate the creation of the WebDriver into the SeleniumJupiter swap out the WebDriverManager with your own implementaion using: this.getConfig().setManager(new MyWebDriverManager)), there you just overwrite the path to the binaries with options.setBinary(browserBinary.toFile());
